# commandButton performs action but doesn't perform upfate

Tags: primefaces

I have a commandButton as a part of row in table. It deletes element from list. This list is a value of a table. I know that element deleted successfully, but table doesn't update. How to make it work. Button tags:

```
<p:column style="width:1%">
                    <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" title="Del"
                        icon="ui-icon-close"                                                                    
                        update="attachmentsTable" immediate="true"
                        action="#{myBean.attachTable.deleteAttachment(attachment.id)}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
```

Table tags:

```
<p:dataTable id="attachmentsTable" var="attachment"
                style="width:100%;"
                value="#{myBean.attachTable.attachmentsList}"
                emptyMessage="Empty">
```

Comment: Generally problem solved by updating all form, that contains many tables. But how to perform partial update? `process="@this"` - did not help.

Comment: Give more context to your question: post the rest of your view

Answer (score 0):

Try to use form qualified name, i.e `update=":formWithTable:attachmentsTable"`. Also check for javascript errors in your browser, it usually gives hints about what went wrong...